# Optimize correlated subquery for order events table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, subquery, groupwise-maximum

I have a MariaDB table with order events:

| EVENTID | ORDERID | DATA | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 'stuff1' | 2021-12-17 11:48:00.000 |
| 2 | 1 | 'newstuff1' | 2021-12-17 11:49:00.000 |
| 3 | 1 | 'newerstuff1' | 2021-12-17 11:49:30.000 |
| 4 | 2 | 'stuff2' | 2021-12-17 11:50:00.000 |
| 5 | 3 | 'stuff3' | 2021-12-17 11:51:10.000 |
| 6 | 3 | 'newstuff3' | 2021-12-17 11:52:00.000 |

And I need to get the most recent event for every order.
So for this dataset the result should be

| EVENTID | ORDERID | DATA | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 'newerstuff1' | 2021-12-17 11:49:30.000 |
| 4 | 2 | 'stuff2' | 2021-12-17 11:50:00.000 |
| 6 | 3 | 'newstuff3' | 2021-12-17 11:52:00.000 |

I am achieving this using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM MESSAGES m1
WHERE TIMESTAMP = (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) 
FROM MESSAGES m2 WHERE m1.ORDERID = m2.ORDERID);
```

But this is slow for large volumes so I'd like to know if there is a way to improve the query using a join or grouping. Otherwise I'm open to splitting the data into different tables if that would help.

Comment: What version of Maria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT m3.*
    FROM ( SELECT ORDERID, MAX(TIMESTAMP) AS TIMESTAMP
              FROM MESSAGES m1
              GROUP BY ORDERID ) m2
    JOIN MESSAGES m3 USING(ORDERID, TIMESTAMP);
```

and have

```
INDEX(ORDERID, TIMESTAMP)
```

The query is a "groupwise-max" pattern.

The derived table (subquery) will hop through the index, then look up the rest of the columns from the table.

If there are any duplicate timestamps for a given order id, it will deliver multiple rows.  If that is not desired, see [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table t2
                   WHERE t1.orderid = t2.orderid
                     AND t1.`timestamp` < t2.`timestamp` )
```

I.e. simply select the row if there is no another row with the same order id and with more recent date.

PS. The index by `` (orderid, `timestamp`) `` will improve.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but it's actually slower than my initial quey, at least in my tests.